# Using Terraform to deploy Kubernetes apps

Tags: kubernetes, terraform

I know that using Terraform to deploy your Infra and Kubernetes Cluster is the way to go. However, does it make any sense to use Terraform to also deploy applications on kubernetes cluster? Is this also the way to go?

Thank you

Comment: Have a look at https://helm.sh/

Comment: Not sure it is even possible ...

Comment: I've had some luck using the [Helm provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/helm/index.html) but on the whole I've found it's a little bit awkward and more k8s-native tooling works a little better...YMMV

Answer (score 2):

Though it's not devoid of it's complexities, a better pipeline is Jenkins + Helm + Spinnaker combo.

- Jenkins - CI
- Helm - templating and chart build
- Spinnaker - deploy

Pros:

- Spinnaker is an excellent tool for deployment to kubernetis.
- It can be made aware of multiple environment ,so cloud pipeline are
  easier to build.
- Natively integrates with most of the cloud providers like AWS,Azure,PCF etc

Cons:

- On the flip side it's a little heavy tool as it is comprised of a
  bunch of microservices and configuration can get under your skin.

Answer (score 1):

I maintain the [Kustomization provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/kbst/kustomization/latest) as an alternative integration of Kubernetes manifests into Terraform.

It has three main advantages over alternative options:

1. Every K8s resource is tracked individually in the Terraform state. This gives you a preview of changes in the plan phase. And also enables destroy-and-recreate plans in case of changes to immutable fields.
2. The provider allows you to use native Kubernetes YAML unchanged. No need to translate everything into HCL like with the Kubernetes provider.
3. Being based on Kustomize, it allows you to use Kustomize's overlay approach. But by defining the overlay in Terraform, you can use Terraform variables, module outputs and so on, to patch the Kubernetes resources.

You can of course use the provider's data sources and resources directly, but the most convenient way is probably via this module:

```
module "example_manifests" {
  source  = "kbst.xyz/catalog/custom-manifests/kustomization"
  version = "0.1.0"

  configuration_base_key = "default"
  configuration = {
    default = {
      resources = [
        # list of paths to K8s YAML files
        "${path.root}/path/to/a/kubernetes/resource.yaml"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze) mentioned, you can combine terraform with helm.
You can find more information abut terraform provider [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/helm/index.html)
and [here](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-helm)
As per terraform documentation

> "install_tiller" - (Optional) Install Tiller if it is not already installed. Defaults to true.
>   You can use also ansible with helm packages manager [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/helm_module.html):

Please take a lookk for othe automated tools described shortly [here](https://raygun.com/blog/best-devops-tools/) and [here](https://www.weave.works/blog/continuous-delivery-tools-for-kubernetes-part-1). like jenkins mentioned by [Shirine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5501217/shirine).

Please take a lookk for othe automated tools described shortly [here](https://raygun.com/blog/best-devops-tools/) like jenkins mentioned bye @Shirine

There are different solutions. Depending on your needs you should consider factors like: paid/free solutions, for developers/teams, preferred platform, other factors like security, increasing transparency, collaboration and availability.

Hope this help